# pyodbc connecting to named instance

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I've been tearing my hair out trying to pin point the error when connecting to a SQL Server named instance using pyodbc on a linux box. I can connect fine when connecting to other SQL Servers that are not using a named instance. The example below works on a server without a named instance:

```
import pyodbc

DB_WMS_NJ62 = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;PORT=1433;DATABASE=dbname;UID=dbuserid;PWD=dbpass'
conn = pyodbc.connect(DB_WMS_NJ62)
```

This connects correctly and allows me to execute queries.

Below is my problematic code.  Changing the IP, adding a named instance, and changing to the designated port 63810

```
import pyodbc

DB_WMS_ONTMOD2 = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\\fontanasql;PORT=63810;DATABASE=dbname;UID=dbuserid;PWD=dbpass'
conn = pyodbc.connect(DB_WMS_ONTMOD2)
```

Running the above, i receve the error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any help appreciated.

Resolution:
Gord Thompson's suggestion worked. Those were my exact mistakes.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC drivers do not use a PORT= parameter. Instead, they use the port number appended to the server name/address with a comma, e.g.

```
SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,63810
```

Also, the ODBC driver for Linux is unable to resolve instance names. However, you can use [sqlserverport](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) to work around that.

Finally, note that when specifying a target server you should use either the instance name (if possible) *or* the port number, not both.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem and worked for me after adding port with Database server name. sqlserveeport module is very helpful to identify the port number as seen many times we all are referring default port 1433
https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport